# Grails allErrors in JSON

Tags: json, grails

How do I include the errors.allErrors in the JSON rendered?

I would like my JSON to look something like this:

```
{id:10
 name:""
  _errors: [{name:"Name cannot be blank"}], 
  children: [{field:"value", _errors:[]}, ...] 
}
```

etc

So that when using something like Angular we have the errors in the same "class" as the fields. Returning the errors in another map doesn't work when you have a complex tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is when you give up that find the answer.

As always Grails has it covered with the Marshallers plugin (https://grails.org/plugin/marshallers)

Adding in the plugin then adding the following to the Domain Class

```
static marshalling={
    json{
        angular{    
            virtual {
                _errors {value, json ->                     
                    json.value (com.ocom.grails.ErrorsMap.generateMap(value));          
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where com.ocom.grails.ErrorsMap.generateMap(value) will take the domain class and return an Array of Errors

In the controller return the JSON like this

```
render JSON.use('angular') {responseJson as JSON}
```

This worked with Grails 2.3.11

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get pretty JSON in grails is from MAP, so:

```
[id:10,
 name:"",
 _errors: [name:"Name cannot be blank"], 
 children: [field:"value", _errors:[], ...] 
] as grails.converters.JSON
```